# peticion .get en node js desde api rest

Tags: nodejs

Tengo un problema estoy enviando los datos de mi formulario mediante ajax a una api rest de esta forma

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'direccion de la api',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
          firstName: first_name.val(),
          lastName: last_name.val(),
          dni: dni.val(),
          cellphone: cellphone.val(),
          email: email.val(),
          password: password.val(),
          passwordconfirm: passwordconfirm.val(),
        },
        success: function (res){
          console.log(res);
        }
      })
```

se supone que en la API me retornan los errores como por ejemplo las contraseñas no coinciden o el email ya existe pero en formato json, mi duda es como llamar los errores que me envian de la API?
no se si mi estructura esta bien hecha:

```
router.post('/user/signup',(req,res) => {
  axios.get('direccion de la api')
  .then((response)=>{
    console.log(response);
  })
  .cath((err)=>{
    console.log(err);
  });
  res.redirect('/user/signup');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es capturar el error que devuelve el servidor para tu petición, el método `ajax` admite un callback para el caso de error, de igual forma que lo acepta para la resolución satisfactoria de la petición:

```js
$.ajax({
        url: 'direccion de la api',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
          firstName: first_name.val(),
          lastName: last_name.val(),
          dni: dni.val(),
          cellphone: cellphone.val(),
          email: email.val(),
          password: password.val(),
          passwordconfirm: passwordconfirm.val(),
        },
        success: function (res){
          console.log(res);
        },
        error: function(request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            // Aqui puedes capturar el error y realizar una acción u otra en función del error que devuelva tu servidor.
        })
      })
```

Esa función de error recibe como parámetros `request` que es la petición en si, `textStatus` que es el código de error (ej: 404, 401, 500) y `errorThrown` que es el texto del error, en caso de que tu servidor lo controle, será el texto que devuelva este.
)